# Application design for SaaS using third party billing/subscriptions system (ChargeBee)

Tags: saas, application-design, chargebee

I've built a SaaS solution which is currently free to use. I'm just starting to build out the ability for users to upgrade and pay for it on a monthly or annual basis.

I want to offload all of the "difficult" stuff so that I can focus on building a good product. By "difficult", I am referring to things like the payment processing, backend admin functionality, billing analytics, PCI compliance, etc.

I'm using [ChargeBee](https://www.chargebee.com/) with Stripe as the gateway.

However, I'm not sure exactly how to structure the application. I'm a full-stack developer, but am aware that my knowledge of architecture is limited, and I don't want to corner myself by building a bad solution.

The signup process will be something like this:

1. [my application] user enters their email, password, and chooses which plan they want
2. [hosted on ChargeBee] user is redirected to the hosted ChargeBee payment page and enters their billing details
3. [my application] user is redirected back to my application with subscription/user data in the response

Now my main questions are:

- what data should I be storing and relying on in both applications (my own, and ChargeBee)?
- How do I know what access level to give the user once they're in my domain - do I ping ChargeBee in my middleware to find out what plan the user is on, OR should that data ALSO be kept in my own application AS WELL AS in ChargeBee (like double accounting?)

I don't see a problem with pinging ChargeBee to return the subscription info all of the time, but then again is that the "right" thing to do? If so, should I cache the ChargeBee info for a user upon logging in?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I'm facing the same situation now that you did when writing this question. If I may ask, how did you ultimately solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see a problem with pinging ChargeBee to return the subscription info all of the time, but then again is that the "right" thing to do? If so, should I cache the ChargeBee info for a user upon logging in?

I don't think there's any right answers here. Do note however that Chargebee has a 150 API calls a minute limitation. A cache can be a source of bugs so I would prefer querying Chargebee directly if it's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that I founded [Cheddar](https://www.getcheddar.com), a competitor of ChargeBee.

Congrats on deciding to use a subscription management service provider. Often, folks build their own and regret it later...

I'd say, in general terms, you'll want to avoid storing anything that's available at ChargeBee and vice versa. Keeping that sort of double storage in sync can be problematic. I'm not intimately familiar with how ChargeBee fits into access control of a merchant application but I'm guessing they expect that they'll be pinged for information in the way you're suggesting.

You'll want to avoid hitting their API at an unreasonable level. It'd be easy to fall into an architecture where current info is requested from upstream on every page view. You've already considered that, it seems... Here are some other concerns you might contemplate:

1. Overhead of calling an upstream API on every page view will make your app seem slow to the end user.
2. If ever an upstream service if unavailable, so is your app.

Using a basic cache mechanism to mitigate these issues is a good way to go. There's obviously lots of ways to do that. Just keep the expiry short to start with. Say, 1 hour. You could lengthen it down the road. If you want to go further, and assuming ChargeBee supports webhooks, you might consider setting up your app to listen for relevant hooks that might change a user's status and invalidate any cache for that user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using chargebee with stripe from over a year and i find it reliable . I think according to your flow , you should store customerId and if required the subscriptionid and some basic data of customer.